# How high can propeller airplanes fly?

Tags: aircraft-performance, propeller, altitude

Is there a maximum height a propeller airplane could fly?

Some **lower bounds** for maximum flying altitude:

- 12,000m (39,370ft): [Antonow An-70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-70), produced 1994
- 12,310m (40,387ft): [Lockheed Martin C-130J Super Hercules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_C-130J_Super_Hercules), delivered in 2012
- 12,500m (41,010ft): [Piaggio P.180 Avanti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piaggio_P.180_Avanti), production started in 1986
- 29,523m (96,860ft): [NASA Helios HP01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Helios), record altitude reached in 2001

Just for comparison: [Low earth orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit) is about 160,000m.

**Upper bounds**: I don't know. I guess at some point there is not enough air to get lifted.
And nobody build an airplane with solar cells that flies to space.

I guess important factors for such an upper bound are:

- Weight of the airplane,
- Size, shape and speed of the propellers
- Speed of the propellers

Comment: It seems like you already answered the question. What exactly are you expecting from an answer here?

Comment: No, I just said that current prototypes (or rather: the best I found) can fly at least 29,523m high. I want to know if, for example, we had more efficient solar cells / lighter material they could even get to outer space. I guess not. I guess there might be a hight (below 160,000m) that cannot be reached.

Comment: And I would like to know if I got all factors which determine how high a plane can get.

Comment: If we extrapolate from the Helios, no matter how thin the air gets, if you can make a subsonic airfoil light enough, it should be able to be propeller driven. There is a limiting issue, which is that the speed of sound decreases with altitude, so a subsonic aircraft might have to travel very slowly (in indicated airspeed, which is not necessarily slow speed over the ground).

Comment: Would [aviation.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Do you consider a jet engine to be a fancy propeller? In other words - is this about "moving the air around you" versus "relying on the thrust of the expelled propellant" (rocket)? A high bypass jet is really a propeller that is driven by a turbine. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Qmechanic: Yes, probably. I didn't know that that site existed.

Comment: You don't specify the type of propulsion, which makes a difference... but essentially if you had a big enough propellor, wings large enough to create lift and a non-air-dependant engine (eg not a conventional or jet engine) then you could go to the very edge of the atmosphere. As long as there is air to push, you can push it. That's the theoretical limit.

Comment: you don't need a propeller to get up into the flight levels. Gliders regularly fly in the flight levels, sometimes over 30,000ft

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is a matter of power source (and engine aspiration in case of air breathing engines), wing loading and aerodynamic efficiency. With current technology, the limit is around 100.000 ft (30 km), as proven by [Pathfinder and especially Helios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_aircraft#NASA_Pathfinder.2C_Pathfinder_Plus.2C_Centurion.2C_and_Helios). I doubt that much more is possible with really useable aircraft.

Aerodynamics first: The altitude factor of $c_l \cdot Ma^2$ tells you how much lift can be produced at a given flight Mach number, and the wing loading then gives you the minimum density for sustained flight. 0.4 is a good value for subsonic $c_l \cdot Ma^2$, and 30 kg/m$^2$ is a feasible wing loading for flight at 30 km. See [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/is-an-atmospheric-geostationary-satellite-feasible-with-current-technology/3348#3348) for more detail.

If the power source needs ambient air (piston engine), the plane needs triple-stage compressors or turbochargers, which have been [tested up to 20 km altitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grob_Strato_2C) and should be good for maybe 24 km. They are finicky devices; [Boeing Condor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Condor) rarely flew at its maximum power because the stages of the turbochargers would oscillate in an alternating sequence of surges. One stage would race ahead, causing the other to surge, which made the first surge and free up the other to race ahead, and so on.

Above approximately 24 km, solar-electric propulsion looks like the best option currently. In all cases you can only fly subsonic, so the minimum practical wing loading will limit the maximum altitude. Aircraft like Helios are very delicate already, so they can only be launched in calm weather and are at risk of being blown away by high altitude winds. Payload is minimal, and depending what the aircraft is supposed to do besides flying high will give you a limit on the maximum altitude between 24 and 30 km.

Going to orbit in a propeller driven device is completely illusory. There is not enough matter to push against at higher altitudes, and the theoretical propeller diameter would be measured in Kilometers (or miles, if you prefer that unit). The structural mass would be prohibitive. Also, propeller thrust is inversely proportional to flight speed, and there is no way to accelerate with a propeller to escape velocity. The thrust would be just a rounding error away from zero at 7.9 km/s.

This speed is required to escape earth's gravity by flying fast enough around it so that the centripetal force equals the aircraft's weight and is called orbital velocity. The higher the orbit becomes, the more energy is required to reach it. In order to gain enough energy, a propeller aircraft would accelerate in the atmosphere to a speed quite a bit higher than the desired orbital velocity and then convert that kinetic energy to potential energy to lift its trajectory above at least 100 km, the internationally recognized altitude where spaceflight starts. Note that this phase of the flight requires inverted flight if the acceleration takes some time. The maximum flight Mach number would need to be maybe 12 or even 15 so this maneuver is possible at all.

In short: Going to orbit with a propeller? Forget it!

Comment: @user2813274: You are right, I should be more explicit.

Comment: "The higher the orbit becomes, the faster the aircraft needs to go." – Other way around, isn't it? For circular orbits, the orbital velocity is slower the higher up you go.

Comment: @TannerSwett What I meant is that you need to start with a higher velocity in order to reach the higher orbit. I admit that was not expressed clearly. I hope my edit improved the answer.

Comment: @TannerSwett Sorry for replying to such an old post, but I wanted to say that Orbital Mechanics is bizarrely counter-intuitive. In order to reach a high, slow-speed orbit you need to accelerate to put energy into your orbit. Inversely, to move from a high-altitude low-speed orbit to a high-speed low-altitude one, you have to decelerate and remove energy from your orbit. Slowing down is speeding up and speeding up is slowing down. Crazy, right?

Comment: Is the question meant to exclude situations where meteorological "lift" such as mountain wave assists the aircraft in climbing to high altitude?

Comment: @quietflyer. Wouldn't that make the question meaningless? When it's about propeller aircraft, the prop should do the lifting.

Answer (score 1):

**If talking "crewed" (aka "manned") aircraft, using propellers:**

The **Grob Strato 2C** was a German experimental high altitude research aircraft. Powered by two turbocharged **piston engines (dual PUSHER propellers)** and featuring an extremely long span wing of composite construction, one aircraft was built in the 1990s, **but was abandoned despite setting a world altitude record for piston-engined aircraft on its last flight *("crewed" record, not over-all)***

**1995, August 4: 60,897 ft / 18,561 m**

***Note**: Unpressurised cabin record is the Caproni Ca.161:
1938, October 22: 56,850 ft / 17,330 m*

**The theoretical "max altitude" a propeller would remain effective is "the stratopause (formerly misspeak, 48,000 to 55,000 m above sea level)"** ...the level of the atmosphere which is the boundary between two layers: the stratosphere and the mesosphere. In the stratosphere, the temperature increases with altitude, and **the stratopause is the region where a maximum in the temperature occurs.**

***IMHO***: Past this region there is not enough particle density for practical propeller use. This, approx. 50,000m altitude, is "possible" but exceeds any existing technology, at least on designs I have seen (like the previously mentioned NASA Helios's 29,524m)

Answer (score 0):

A P3 orion made 45,018 in 1971.

Comment: That's technically an answer, but way too short on detail - especially as you know it's not the record.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where can I find news and information about this flight?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Some info here: https://www.avgeekery.com/p-3-orion-turboprop-46000-feet-happened/