# Are there any aviation vehicles for Internet service?

Tags: radio-communications, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

Facebook announced on Wednesday (2018.06.27) that it is [ending its Aquila drone program](https://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/telecom/internet/facebook-pulls-out-of-secret-spaceport-internet-drone-tests) after four years of development. Aquila was a high-altitude platform station (HAPS) system ***designed to deliver internet*** in remote locations.

The solar-powered Aquila was designed to fly between 60,000 and 90,000 feet and to stay aloft for up to 90 days at a time, while providing broadband coverage to a 60-mile-wide area on the ground. The drone flew twice in 2016-2017.

**Do any organizations or governments have or plan to provide Internet service via a drone or other aircraft?**

[image]

[source](https://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/telecom/internet/facebook-pulls-out-of-secret-spaceport-internet-drone-tests)

Comment: Do you mean heavier-than-air, or does Google Loon count?

Comment: If by "plan" you mean something to be executed and not reaching it's target is considered a failure, then the answer is probably no. None of the existing proposals is that firm.

Comment: The linked article mentions one project by Google ([Skybender](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/jan/29/project-skybender-google-drone-tests-internet-spaceport-virgin-galactic)) and that again one more by DARPA ([mobile hotspots](https://www.darpa.mil/news-events/2014-04-07)). Since DARPA has less than global ambitions, this one looks likely to succeed.

Comment: Related: [Is an “atmospheric geostationary satellite” feasible with current technology?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/is-an-atmospheric-geostationary-satellite-feasible-with-current-technology)